# Any libraries or frameworks for building a SSO proxy?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I've been tasked with determining the feasibility of building an application that would act as a proxy between platforms that offer single sign-on capabilities.

Our "platform" offers SAML Service Provider capabilities, and we have some customers that provide their own SAML IDP and Identity Store. We have other customers that use different single sign-on technologies, such as oAuth, OpenID, or third-party Web Services. Some customers use a combination of these technologies.

The goal of the proxy would be to standardize and reduce the complexity of each customer's SSO integration on the platform. Currently, we're required to customize each implementation between the platform and the customer's Website(s).

I'm having difficulty finding frameworks, libraries, or functions for proxying between SSO protocols such as SAML and oAuth, or SAML and a third-party Web Service.

I'm wondering if anyone has experience building something similar and can recommend solutions that worked for them.

I've put together a diagram that illustrates what we're trying to accomplish below.

[image: SSO Proxy]

Comment: Welcome to InfoSec.SE! Security.SE focuses on high-level architecture of the security itself. Your question is about specific technologies and how to interface with them programatically. So it's really a software question, not a security question. I'm going to flag this for migration to StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm sorry but this should never have been migrated to SO. Asking for a tool/framework tends to end up with a lot of spam from representatives of different tools/frameworks. That said there are a lot of such tools. MS ADFS can do it in some scenarios. Azure AD as well. There's also IdentityServer3 that's open source.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Bitly project on GitHub:

https://github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy

It supports multiple identity providers

hth

Comment: This is a link only answer to a off-topic question. Please prepare for this answer to be deleted soon.